# Enable HTTP compression (gzip, deflate, brotli) on Cloud Run hosted on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting

I have a service running on Cloud Run that is hosted by Firebase Hosting, this is my `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/play/**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "play",
          "region": "us-central1",
          "pinTag": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know that is possible to set custom headers, but I want to know if Firebase Hosting can compress the result of my service running on Run.

For example:

User access `mysite.com/play/foo.js`

Run will handle this request and it will return a javascript, but, my web server doesn't compress it.

So I want know if Firebase Hosting can compress, without any configuration there is no compression, I have checked.

EDIT: For example, in Kubernetes, you have a pod that does not serve gzip, but you have the ingress in front of it with gzip enabled, thus, your content is compressed. I expected the same from Firebase Hosting.

Comment: I know one option is to use a sidecar (Nginx), or implement on my service, but I am willing more to do this on Firebase.

Comment: Oh that is frustrating, its a built in option for Internet Information Services that you don't have to set via the code normally, but Google gonna Goog.

Comment: Why not configure your web server on cloud run to compress the responses?  Since you are building your own docker image, you can configure it any way you want, at the cost of doing a deep dive into building that docker image by your own spec.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am a developer, that said, I am lazy.

Comment: What is `my web server`? Firebase provides no compute processing. There is nothing running in Firebase to compress the response. You must compress the response in your application.

Comment: @JohnHanley, for example, in Kubernetes, you have a pod that does not serve gzip, but you have the ingress in front of it with gzip enabled, thus, your content is compressed. I expected the same from Firebase Hosting.

Comment: You can expect something, but that is not how Firebase works. Firebase is simply serving files from Cloud Storage. If you want features beyond Cloud Storage + CDN, you must implement them yourself. The magic that Firebase provides is authorization and database. Beyond that, it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up using a sidecar in Run with Nginx, with compression enabled and caching headers.

For my use, it was totally impractical to use Firebase Hosting because it does aggressive caching of the Run responses that is only cleared with a new deploy.

Unlike Cloudflare, there is no option to flush!

Comment: Note: Cloud Run does not require a sidecar to implement Nginx. Add details to your post on what you configured with an explanation of why. IMHO the correct solution is to correctly implement your application to compress responses and to provide the correct HTTP cache response headers. Nginx is not required for Cloud Run applications for either feature.

Comment: I do not want to change my application, there is no way to add gzip on it because some tech limitations, so, my alternative is to use an instance of Nginx to compress.